# Find the spectral projection of a positive operator explicitly

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $a$ be an element in $\mathcal B(\mathcal H)$. How can one show that $\chi_{(0,\infty)}(aa^∗)=[a\mathcal H]$? Here $[a\mathcal H]$ is the projection corresponding to the closed subspace $\overline{a\mathcal H}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 
$$
(a\mathcal H)^\perp=\ker a^*=\ker aa^*=(aa^*\mathcal H)^\perp.
$$
So $[a\mathcal H]=[aa^*\mathcal H]$.

Now, from $t\,\chi_{(0,\infty)}(t)=t$ on $[0,\infty)$, you get 
$$
\chi_{(0,\infty)}(aa^*)\,aa^*=aa^*\,\chi_{(0,\infty)}(aa^*)=aa^*. 
$$
So
$$
\chi_{(0,\infty)}(aa^*)\,\overline{a\mathcal H}=\chi_{(0,\infty)}(aa^*)\overline{aa^*\mathcal H}=\overline{aa^*\mathcal H}=\overline{a\mathcal H}.
$$
This shows that $\chi_{(0,\infty)}(aa^*)\geq[a\mathcal H]$. Conversely, $\chi_{(0,\infty)}(aa^*)$ can be written as a limit of polynomials $p_n(aa^*)$ with $p_n(0)=0$, so $$[a\mathcal H]\,\chi_{(0,\infty)}(aa^*)=\chi_{(0,\infty)}(aa^*),$$'
showing that $\chi_{(0,\infty)}(aa^*)\leq[a\mathcal H]$.

Comment: $\chi_{(0,\infty)}(t) = 1$ for $t \in (0,\infty)$ ?

Comment: Yes. $\ \ \ \ \ $

Answer (score 0):

As @Martin Argerami suggests, we need to prove that $\chi_{(0,\infty)}(a^*a) = [aa^*\mathcal{H}]$.

Since $\sigma(aa^*) \subseteq [0, \infty\rangle$ we have
$$\chi_{(0,\infty)} = 1 - \chi_{\{0\}}$$
In general [we have](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3126784/144766) $\chi_{\{0\}}(aa^*) = [\ker aa^*]$ so
$$\chi_{(0,\infty)}(aa^*) = 1(aa^*) - \chi_{\{0\}}(aa^*) = I-[\ker aa^*]= [aa^*\mathcal{H}]$$

The last equality is clear from $\mathcal{H} = \ker aa^* \oplus \overline{aa^*\mathcal{H}}$.

Comment: What do you mean by the last inequality?

Comment: @kk91 I meant the last equality, that $[\ker aa^*]+[aa^*\mathcal{H}]= I$.